# Вася (Петя (Коля)) - СКОБИРОВАНИЕ С ПРОБЕЛИРОВАНИЕМ

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вот если Вася - это Петя, а Петя - это Коля, то как данную ситуацию можно записать? Вот такое скобирование с пробелированием не будет ошибкой?

ВОТ:

> **Вася (Петя (Коля))**

Comment: Думаю, не будет, даже если напишешь без пробелов и с маленьких букв, всё равно не ясно зачем это нагромождение *скобирования и пробелирования*.

Comment: Благодарю Папу Карло за его сына!

Comment: НЕЯСНО надо слитно написать, наверное. Можно ведь заменить на НЕПОНЯТНО?

Comment: Да, можно вобще слитно написать всё, всё равно смысла не прибавится (ВасяКоляПетя). И твоему отцу тоже привет.

Comment: Для Табуретовича (это как бы школьное прозвище): Предикативное наречие может иметь две формы  письма (неясно и не ясно). В данной ситуации это выбор автора (отрицание или утверждение признака). Избегайте по возможности однозначных и всегда ясных решений))

Comment: Так я и говорю не утвердительно, а употребляю слово "наверное". Где здесь однозначность? Вам, Варвара, нужно внимательнее читать. А про Табуретовича - фантазия ваша. Или характер дурной. Я ж не знаю :)

Comment: А между "ясно" и "зачем" тоже не нужна запятая у Буратино?

Comment: Тогда так: раздельное написание "не ясно" Буратино допустимо, но не предпочтительно. Но допустимо лишь в том случае, если Буратино знал правило и осуществлял выбор. Если же он не мучился над этим вопросом, то это скорее ошибка. Всё может быть, ибо он продал свою азбуку и колпачок с кисточкой и пошёл вместо школьных занятий на цирковое представление.

Comment: А что это вы так разволновались? Значит, запятые умеете ставить? Нам такие люди нужны. Вот самый простой вопрос для вас (только чтобы грамотно было). rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474290/… А это немного потруднее, но я верю в вас rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474291/…